# Alternatives to readability extension in Google Chrome

Tags: chrome, reading

I have problem finding a good way to view web pages that offer too small margins when viewed in full screen mode. The problem is that the line width becomes too large so it is difficult to read. Of course I can resize the browser window to force a smaller line width, but this is not an optimal solution.

I usually browse in full screen mode in Google Chrome on my laptop.
I tried the [readability extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readability/oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi?hl=en) for Google Chrome, but unfortunately it does not work for all pages. For example this page:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html

will be transformed into a nice looking page, with wide margins that the user can adjust, to set the preferred line width, but the problem is that much of the text from the original page is missing.

Is there any good alternatives to increase margins/reduce line width to enhance readability in Google Chrome?

Comment: May be Pocket or Evernote Clearly like that.

Comment: @Vembu I tried Pocket now, it seems it has the same problem as the readability extension. Missing text, and also too large margins..

Comment: @Vembu I could not get Evernote clearly too work. It installed fine, but when I click the icon nothing happens.. (I am using Ubuntu 14.04) .. thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you another alternatives:

1. **[Pocket](https://getpocket.com/)**

   Someone has already mentioned this extensions.

   > Pocket used to help people save interesting articles, videos and more
   >   from the web for later enjoyment. Once saved to Pocket, the list of
   >   content is visible on any device — phone, tablet or computer. It can
   >   be viewed while waiting in line, on the couch, during commutes or
   >   travel — even offline ([source](https://getpocket.com/about)).

   If you use Firefox, Pocket has already installed by default since Firefox 38.0.5. OK, I know you use Chrome browser, don't worry it [exists](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket/mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk?hl=en) too. Here below is the screencapture of your example page which is viewed from "Reader View" mode Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Reader View Mode in Mozilla Firefox]

2. **[Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com)**

   Instapaper is same as the Pocket. But, you can give highlight in your saved article. The features will be given to you in not far what you will get from Pocket. By the way, you can set the background, font type, and width of your saved article. This extension [exists](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instapaper/ldjkgaaoikpmhmkelcgkgacicjfbofhh?hl=en) on Google Chrome. Here below is screencapture of your example page using Instapaper:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I created and maintain an open source extension called [**Just Read**](https://justread.link) which makes reading articles a lot more pleasant. It has an attractive built in theme but allows you to customize the theme or add your own completely new one.

It has features such as

- Removal of superfluous material such as ads, popus, comments, and styling
- A GUI editor of the default theme
- A full CSS editor for making your theme customized
- Cross device syncing
- A "User selection mode" so you can select the text to read on tricky pages like the one you linked
- A "Deletion mode" so you can hide parts on the article once you pull it up in Just Read format
- Keyboard shortcuts to enable these different modes

There's also a premium version that lets you shared simplified pages and have some other additional features.

[image]
<sub>This is the default theme applied to a blog post of mine.</sub>

The difficulty with extensions like this are that web pages are structured in so many ways in the HTML, so obtaining the content isn't easy if the developers make the site poorly. That's why I try to obtain it programmatically but let users also choose for themselves if need be

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote clearly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearly/iooicodkiihhpojmmeghjclgihfjdjhj) seems to be a good replacement for the readability extension. It was tested on Ubuntu 14.04 using Chrome version 42.0.2311.135.

You may need to restart your browser after adding the extension. Also installing the [Evernote webapplication](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web/lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol?hl=en) would be an option to transfer clips from Evernote clearly to a central Evernote repository.